# Construction of holomorphic line bundles on complex torus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

This is an argument for constructing positive line bundles on complex torus. From some knowledge of Abelian varieties, such as Riemann conditions, we know that it is wrong. But I don't know where this argument goes wrong.

Let $\{ v_{s,i} \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be sequences of points in $\mathbb{C}^2$, where $s=1,2,3,4$. Suppose that $v_{1,i} ,v_{2,i} ,v_{3,i} ,v_{4,i} $ converge to $(1,0),( \sqrt{-1} ,0 ) ,(0,1),( 0,\sqrt{-1} ) $ respectively when $i$ tends to $\infty $. We will denote by $ \Lambda_i $ the lattice generated by $v_{1,i} ,v_{2,i} ,v_{3,i} ,v_{4,i} $. Similarly, we will write the lattice generated by $(1,0),( \sqrt{-1} ,0 ) ,(0,1),( 0,\sqrt{-1} ) $ as $ \Lambda_\infty $. Then the quotient spaces $X_i =\mathbb{C}^2 /\Lambda_i $ are $2$-dimensional complex torus, and $X_\infty =\mathbb{C}^2 /\Lambda_\infty $ is an Abelian variety. Let $\left( L_\infty , h_\infty \right) $ be a Hermitian holomorphic line bundle on $X_\infty$ such that $-\sqrt{-1} \partial\bar{\partial} \log h_\infty =2\pi \omega_{Euc} $, where $\omega_{Euc} $ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Let $\pi_i $ denote the projection map $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2 /\Lambda_i =X_i $, and $\pi_\infty $ denote the projection map $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2 /\Lambda_\infty =X_\infty $. Choosing $N$ points $\{ x_j \}_{j=1}^{N} $ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $X_{\infty} = \cup_{j=1}^{N} \pi_\infty \left( B_{10^{-3}}\; (x_j) \right) $. Since $ \pi_\infty \left( B_{10^{-1}}\; (x_j) \right) \cong B_{10^{-1}}\; (x_j)  $ is a Stein manifold, we see that $L_{\infty} |_{ \pi_\infty \left( B_{10^{-1}}\; (x_j) \right)} $ is trivial, and hence we can find holomorphic sections $e_{\infty ,j} \in H^0 \left( \pi_\infty \left( B_{10^{-1}}\; (x_j) \right) , L_\infty \right) $ satisfying that $h_{\infty} \left(  e_{\infty, j} ,e_{\infty ,j} \right) =e^{-\pi d^2_{j}} $, where $d_j $ is the distance from $\pi_{\infty} ( x_j )$. Let $f_{jk ,\infty} $ be the holomorphic function on $\pi_\infty \left( B_{10^{-1}}\; (x_j) \right) \cap \pi_\infty \left( B_{10^{-1}}\; (x_k) \right) \neq \emptyset $ satisfying $e_{\infty ,j} =f_{jk,\infty} e_{\infty ,k} $. For sufficiently large $i$, we have
$$ \pi_i^{-1} \left( \pi_i (B_{10^{-2} }\; (x_k) ) \right) \cap B_{10^{-2}} \;(x_j) \Subset \pi_\infty^{-1} \left( \pi_\infty (B_{10^{-1} }\; (x_k) ) \right) \cap B_{10^{-1}} \;(x_j) . $$
Consider the following holomorphic functions on each $ \pi_i^{-1} \left( \pi_i (B_{10^{-2} }\; (x_j) ) \right) \cap \pi_i^{-1} \left( \pi_i (B_{10^{-2} }\; (x_k) ) \right) \neq \emptyset :$
$$ \psi_{jk,i} = \left( f_{jk,\infty} \circ \pi_\infty \circ \left( \pi_{i} |_{B_{10^{-2}} \; (x_j)} \right)^{-1} \right) \cdot \left( f_{jk,\infty} \circ \pi_\infty \circ \left( \pi_{i} |_{B_{10^{-2}} \; (x_k)} \right)^{-1} \right) .$$
Then $\{ \psi_{jk,i} \}_{j,k=1}^{N} $ is a family of transition functions on $X_i$ for sufficiently large $i$. It determines a line bundle $L_i$ on $X_i$.

Choosing cut-off functions $\eta_{j} \in C_0^{\infty} (B_{10^{-2}} \; (x_j)) $ for each $j=1,\cdots ,N$, satisfying that $0\leq \eta\leq 1$ and $\eta_j |_{B_{10^{-3}} \; (x_j) } =1 $. Set $$ \eta_{j,i} = \frac{\eta_{j} \circ \left( \pi_i |_{ \pi_i (B_{10^{-2} }\; (x_j) )} \right)^{-1} }{ \sum_{l=1}^{N} \eta_{l} \circ \left( \pi_i |_{ \pi_i (B_{10^{-2} }\; (x_l) )} \right)^{-1} } \in C_0^{\infty} (\pi_i \left( B_{10^{-2}} \; (x_j) \right) ) .$$ Then $$h_{i} \big|_{\pi_i (B_{10^{-2} } \; (x_j) )} = e^{- \sum_{l} \eta_{l,i} \left( 2\pi d^2_{l,i} \; - \; 2\log | \psi_{jl,i} \;|  \right) } $$ gives a Hermitian metric $h_i$ on $L_i$, where $d_{l,i}$ is the distance from $\pi_i (x_l)$. Letting $i\to\infty $, we see that $$\left| \psi_{jk,i} \right| \circ \pi_{i} \to \left| f_{jk,\infty} \right|^2 \circ \pi_\infty = e^{\pi d^2_k -\pi d_j^2} \circ \pi_\infty $$ on $ \pi_i^{-1} \left( \pi_i (B_{10^{-2} }\; (x_k) ) \right) \cap B_{10^{-2}} \;(x_j) $ uniformly. Note that the functions $\pi d^2_{j,i} - \log | \psi_{jl,i} | -\pi d^2_{k,i} + \log | \psi_{kl,i} | $ are pluriharmonic. Hence we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
-\sqrt{-1} \partial\bar{\partial} \log h_i & = & \sqrt{-1} \partial\bar{\partial} \left( \sum_{l} \eta_{l,i} \left( 2\pi d^2_{l,i} \; - \; 2\log | \psi_{jl,i} |  \right) \right) \\
& = & 4\pi\omega_{Euc} + \sqrt{-1}  \sum_l  \left( 2\pi d^2_{l,i} \; - \; 2\log | \psi_{jl,i} | - 2\pi d^2_{j,i}  \right) \partial\bar{\partial} \eta_{l,i} \\
& & + \sqrt{-1}  \sum_l \partial \eta_{l,i} \wedge \bar{\partial} \left( 2\pi d^2_{l,i} \; - \; 2\log | \psi_{jl,i} | - 2\pi d^2_{j,i} \right) \\
& & + \sqrt{-1}  \sum_l \partial \left( 2\pi d^2_{l,i} \; - \; 2\log | \psi_{jl,i} | - 2\pi d^2_{j,i} \right)  \wedge \bar{\partial} \eta_{l,i} \geq 2\pi \omega_{Euc} ,
\end{eqnarray*}
on $ \pi_i \left( B_{10^{-2}} \; (x_j) \right) $, for sufficiently large $i$. It follows that for sufficiently large $i$, $(L_i ,h_i)$ is a positive line bundle on $X_i$.

But the set of Abelian varieties cannot contain an open subset of the moduli space of complex torus, contradiction.

So, where is this proof wrong?